# Load file into Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to load this file into Postgres using pgfutter

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
Nation  88      85      83      84      78
```

I have tried `pgfutter csv -d $'\t' --skip-header filename`, but it doesn't load the file.

However, it loads this file -

```
1       2       3
AL      017000  "35005"
```

Comment: there might be some issue with data try with --ignore-errors options.

Comment: @dassum I need to load all the data. I cannot just ignore errors.